# Movie and TV show streaming solution similar to sites like putlocker

Tags: streaming-video

I want to be able to stream any movie or TV show on the raspberry pi much like you can do on sites like watchseries and putlocker.

What's the best solution for this with minimum lag and high quality streaming?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109612/discussion-on-question-by-jack-movie-and-tv-show-streaming-solution-similar-to-s).

Comment: I've closed this as off-topic because it is hard to envision a pi-specific answer here, and beyond that the question *reads as if* all you are asking for are streaming site recommendations, which would be more appropriate to our larger sibling site, [Super User](http://superuser.com/)